# In VSCode, is there a way to bind up/down arrow to another key in the file searcher?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open the file searcher by using `Cmd+p` and searching for a file, I would like to be able to scroll through the list of results using `Ctrl+j` and `Ctrl+k` instead of the up/down arrows. Is there a way to set this binding in VSCode?

So for example, say I'm searching for a file, I hit `Cmd+p` and a few results come up. Instead of using the arrow keys to navigate to the specific file I'm looking for, I'd like to be able to use `Ctrl+j` to move down a result and `Ctrl+k` to move up a result.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. Go to keyboard shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and then search for keyboard shortcuts). The commands you are looking for are "Select Next in Quick Open" and "Select Previous in Quick Open", which also bound by default to <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>. (I had the same idea of binding these to j and k, but these bindings suit me well enough).

[image]